# He supplied the terrorist with weapon

Tags: prepositions, direct-objects, indirect-objects

> He supplied the terrorist with weapon

Why not supply here follows norms of direct object, indirect object.

> He supplied the terrorist a weapon
> (Just like he gave me a book)

Comment: It would have to be "with **a** weapon" or "with **the** weapon", because *weapon* is a countable noun.

Answer (score 1):

Words have their own rules.  Sometimes this is called "valency".

If you have studied chemistry, you'll know that (for example) oxygen bonds with two hydrogens, but chlorine bonds with one. Oxygen has a valency of 2, etc.

Words also have valency.  "Give" can take two objects "Give me the book" but "Supply" only has one, but can also be followed by a prepositional phrase: Supply me with the book.

These are just part of the grammar rules of English. Words like "give" that can take two objects are the exception. Most verbs only have a single object.

Comment: Nice explanation. Worth mentioning that the words that can take two objects are called **ditransitive**.

Comment: Wonderful answer!!